# Add rules in .htaccess (outside default WordPress block)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I am trying to add rules in .htaccess via WordPress plugin which works fine and add rules, but gets overwritten sometime.

I know that the rules added using `mod_rewrite_rules` adds the rules in WordPress block, in-between `# BEGIN WORDPRESS` and `# END WORDPRESS`, and all the custom rules should be added outside that block.

Can someone tell me how can I add custom rules outside WordPress block in .htaccess? Here is the code I am using at the moment...

```
function vary_accept_encoding_filter( $rules ) {
  $accept_encoding_header = <<<EOD
  \n<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
  Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>\n
  EOD;

    return $accept_encoding_header . $rules;
}

add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'vary_accept_encoding_filter');
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the Apache rewrite rules are being added by the `save_mod_rewrite_rules()` WordPress function, which basically takes `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` as granted, and only writes between those markers. So if you use the default rewrite rule filters and actions you can't write outside of these markers.

However, I'm not saying that your request is not possible.

I can suggest that you hook on the `update_option_rewrite_rules` action. This one is called after a rewrite rule flush. And on this action, hook a function that adds your rules to the end or beginning (wherever you prefer) of the .htaccess, manually. If you need information on how to manually add rules to the .htaccess, you can see how WordPress does it - refer to the `save_mod_rewrite_rules()` function in `/wp-admin/includes/misc.php`.

Good luck there.

***EDIT***

To add your function to the `update_option_rewrite_rules` hook, do the following:

```
add_action('update_option_rewrite_rules', 'wppsb_enable_gzip_compression');
function wppsb_enable_gzip_compression() {
    // your code here
}
```